# Formatting database info to rows of repeating blocks

Tags: php, database, pdo

I have a database containing several rows of event info (ie state, date, time, location, etc). I have a php homepage and using PDO database connection. I am looking to pull in each row of the database and have them display within a php include that is a styled table-ized block. I want these blocks to repeat side-by-side, displaying each events information in a grid-like pattern.

e.g.
Evt1 Evt2 Evt3
Evt4 Evt5 Evt6
Evt7 Evt8 Evt9

I have successfully connected to my database, and pulled/displayed individual records.

- I need to call all the database information (which I believe I am doing)
- Align columns to associated variables in include page
- Repeat include page with next row from database, so on and so forth

If anyone can steer me in the right direction on where to turn my research, it would be greatly appreciated. The terminology is new to me, so narrowing my search results would be a huge start. Any piece of the puzzle would be greatly welcomed. The evolution of what I have figured out from countless of hours on here and other forums is below. If anyone would like further info, please don't hesitate.

Variables code:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM event_info";
    foreach ($connection->query($sql) as $row) {
}
$state = $row['state'];
$city_state = $row['city_state'];
$regURL = $row['RegURL'];
$date = $row['date'];
$time = $row['time'];
$location = $row['location'];
$address1 = $row['address1'];
$address2 = $row['address2'];
$connection = null;
?>
```

Include code:

```
<div id="eventInfo">
<div class="group">
    <h2><?php echo $state; ?>:</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="localReg">
                <div class=location><?php echo $city_state; ?></div>
                <div class=regNow><a href="<?php echo $regURL; ?>">Register Now</a></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="55">Date:</td>
            <td width="185"><?php echo $date; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="everyOther">Time:</td>
            <td id="everyOther"><?php echo $time; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Location:</td>
            <td><?php echo $location; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="everyOther">Address:</td>
            <td id="everyOther"><?php echo $address1; ?><br><?php echo $address2; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks to me like you basically want to output the HTML with the variables on each iteration of the for each loop

Comment: So you to be clear, you are not having any issue with the database at all, you are just asking a question about HTML layout?  Why not work backwards.  Layout your HTML that way you want it, and then just substitute your PHP variables into it once you have figured out how you want the layout to be?

Comment: What you're looking for is not a table. They're blocks, three in a row. Flexbox can help you with that. And it works really well if you're willing to give up some IE support. There are, however alternative solutions.

Comment: @ Mike, My HTML is where I need it. I am connecting to the database, but my code is only pulling one row of information as opposed to all rows. I am trying to figure out how to pull all rows and display in content blocks side-by-side (e.g. row 0 = content block 1, row1 = content block 2... etc). I may be partially on the right path, but not totally. Looking for some puzzle pieces. Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify. I see this has been changed to the HTML and CSS forum. I am not looking for HTML nor CSS help. What I am looking for is 1. how to get the PHP include to repeat with every row instance of the database and 2. Correctly aligning my PDO database query to pull and populate data from the database.

Comment: You have a loot there, you just are not doing anything inside the loop, so it appears you are just getting the last row. Do your work inside the loop.

Comment: That is exactly what I am getting. Thanks Mike! I'll turn my focus on the loop.